# Win 10 Dell Latitude 3400 - Audio Jack Headphone alone not detecting (Linein is detected)

Tags: windows-10, audio, microphone, 3.5mm

Laptop Model: Dell Latitude 3400

OS: win10 (last update installed on Mar 2021)

Till 2 days back, i was able to use my 3.5mm audio jack headset with my Dell Latitude 3400 laptop for audio. But today when i connect my 3.5mm audio jack, i am not able to see the headphone detected. Win10 is playing audio in built-in speaker of the laptop.

I tried,

1. Uninstall/update Realtek Audio Driver,
2. Validated Privacy settings for Microphone, to allow apps to access microphone,

Guide me in fixing the issue so i can use my headset for speaker & mic instead of built-in speaker/mic.

Note: My 3.5mm audio jack is working when i tested with my phone today.

Comment: Do you have a plugged in HDMI display perhaps? https://superuser.com/questions/1602049/headphone-jack-not-working-dell-inspiron-15-7000

Comment: @petermir No devices plugged in..